# cannot write Chinese in linux

Tags: pdfbox

Question:I can generate Chinese watermark normally in windows environment and macos environment, but it reports an error in linux environment.

linux environment

> java 1.8
> pdfbox 3.0.0-alpha2

The system seems to have successfully installed the font

```
fc-list |grep STFangsong 
/usr/share/fonts/zh_CN/STFANGSO.TTF: STFangsong:style=Regular
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+FFFD (?) in font STFangsong
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:378) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-alpha2.jar!/:3.0.0-alpha2]
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:443) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-alpha2.jar!/:3.0.0-alpha2]
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:335) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-alpha2.jar!/:3.0.0-alpha2]
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getStringWidth(PDFont.java:366) ~[pdfbox-3.0.0-alpha2.jar!/:3.0.0-alpha2]
        at com.tencent.converter.service.PDFBox.processTextOnePage(PDFBox.java:117) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.tencent.converter.service.PDFBox.addTextAllPageWAtermark(PDFBox.java:96) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.tencent.converter.service.PDFBox.addTextWatermark(PDFBox.java:83) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.tencent.converter.service.PDFBox.textWatermark(PDFBox.java:68) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

```
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, new FileInputStream("/usr/local/services/converter-1.0/lib/STFANGSO.TTF"), false);
```

And I tried some fonts that support Chinese, all have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem that works for me.

启动服务时 强制指定编码

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar
```